# PHP DateTime UTC weird behavior

Tags: php, date, datetime, utc

This is a sample code:

```
$d = new DateTime('@1539691200');
$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
var_dump($d);
```

As you see, `DateTime` is constructed from timestamp, so server's timezone is ignored. Then I set timezone to be "UTC" which should be the same everywhere. But anyway here's the output on my machine:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-10-16 13:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

And this is an output from [here](https://3v4l.org/vjsPQ):

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-10-16 12:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

So why does it happen? How the UTC can be different on different servers? Could it be the [timezonedb](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) issue?

Comment: Can you try passing the time zone in the constructor? `$d = new DateTime('@1539691200', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));` If it works I'll put it in an answer. I'm suspecting that possibly it gets adjusted twice?

Comment: the result is same. check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4220eac87577f696b6a8f44b7c851f372592f325

Comment: Are you using a LAMP setup with Windows dual boot? And (just to check) is your machine itself returning the correct UTC? Reason: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/utc-time-is-wrong/46557

Comment: @delboy1978uk there's no difference because `timezone` param is ignored when DateTime is constructed from timestamp. Moreover the timestamp itself remains unchanged too.

Comment: @alpharomeo it's on mac, but the code is running in Docker; I've `ssh`ed into container and checked date there - seems fine: http://prntscr.com/l72guo

Comment: @alpharomeo something is probably wrong with container setup... http://prntscr.com/l72mpj

Comment: @GinoPane - I am also tempeted to say it is a setup / config issue with the container. You could try / read about it more in detail: https://forums.docker.com/t/synchronize-timezone-from-host-to-container/39116 . Sorry dont know much about docker :( - maybe its time I got learning!!